# Music stopping on app close?

Tags: ios, music.app

I have had my iPad on iOS 5.0.1 for a while, and restored it a couple of months ago, wiping all the content. Today I put some music back on (this is iOS 5.1.1 now) and while the music player works, as soon as I close it the music stops (I say 'stops' rather than 'pauses' because using the play button in the multitasking tray starts the song from the beginning as if the Music app hadn't been running.

This does not happen when playing music from other apps such as Dropbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you closing the app?

Comment: 5-fingered swipe inwards, because my home button is flaky, but it also happens when the home button actually works (wear and tear) and when I switch to another app by any method.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using the built-in Music app, or a third-party app?

Comment: Built in music app

Comment: Downvoted because you failed to mention that you were running a jailbroken device, saying instead that you "restored it" implying a fresh iOS install.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the things you will want to try:

1. [Force the Music app to close.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5137)
2. [Restart your device.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1430)
3. [Update to the latest iOS version.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414)

I do not recommend that you close every single app in the multitasking bar. Simply restarting will have the same effect on system resources and is much less inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with there not being enough memory and the Music app trying to accommodate for that by stopping the music the moment you exit it.

While normally you don't have to worry about closing individual apps that are in the app tray, for debugging this issue, I would recommend that close every app that is in the app launcher, then restart the iPad. Once it is restarted, launch only the music app and play the music. Then try going back to the home screen and see if you get different results. There is a possibility that one of the apps you have is misbehaving, and using excess amounts of memory even while it is closed. I have seen this happen many times.

Comment: This has no effect, and I know I'm not out of memory, because I'm jailbroken and I have 300MB free. I know I should un-JB, and I will if necessary, but since 6.1.3 I can't rejailbreak, so this will be a last resort

Comment: I found the problem, but unless any other answers show up I'll award you the bounty when I can

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the problem, it was my own stupid fault and I can't believe I didn't realise earlier. I had installed Backgrounder, a Cydia app to control multitasking, and something in its settings must have had Music terminate on close. How I didn't put two and two together, I don't know.

Comment: Stackexchange is not a support forum. Please try and ask legitimate questions next time.